# Memory speed on Sony camera

Tags: sony, memory-card

I'm planning to purchase a Sony ILCE-QX1-QX1 camera. It seems to be based on the Sony Alpha 5000 or 5100 platform. How fast of a memory chip, and which technologies, can it take advantage of? That is, how much should I spend on the flash memory chip to get the most out of it?

It is especially interesting that it takes Sony's memory as well as MicroSD.

(My Canon 60D for example takes UHS-1 but doesn't really go much faster than Class 10 (UHS is a different protocol) while the 70D will take full advantage. )

Comment: The model name is Sony ILCE-QX1, not ICLE. The camera supports microSD, microSDHC, microSDXC, Memory Stick Micro, and Memory Stick Micro (M2). You won't find details in the specs as to what speed it supports specifically, typically that information is gathered from independent reviewers by simply trying out the cards available. Since that probably doesn't exist yet for this camera, just pickup a standard high quality SD card and you will be just fine.

Comment: UHS-3 is currently the highest speed spec I know of for SD/microSD, and the premium above the cost of lower specs memory is less than 50%. For example, a 64 GB UHS-3 Transcend microSD card at Amazon, http://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-Memory-Adapter--SDSDQUAN-064G-G4A-Version/dp/B00M55C1I2/ref=sr_1_1, is about $US30. High speed helps for video and continuous shooting.

Comment: @dpollitt I thought it strange that the specs didn't say anything about speed. My other cameras at least say what Class is needed for video and video+shooting. The 70D manual states that it uses uhs1. I know what form factor it uses already.

Comment: If it's the same chip as other Alphas, it's not a p&s. I did notice yhe fps is lower than A5100, but I guess I'm one of the few who find it attractive as a Social camera.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that link is for UHas-I.  I suffered from over-choice paralysis when looking up the fastest for the money. 32GB is fine.

Comment: @dpollitt What attracted me is the APS-C sensor in a small package, for better handling of low light than P&S.  The specs for the Alpha 6000 outperform µ4/3 of the same physical size.  See for example http://www.dlugosz.com/zeta/?p=274 where I only got phone pictures.  Broken down into body and lens this should be slim enough to pack as well as a wallet and glasses case.  And the lenses will work on the A6000 if I get that later :)

Comment: Looking more carefully, I see the QX1 isn't as much smaller as the 5000/5100 as I first thought because it is thicker.  But being an unwanted misfit I found it for a hundred dollars cheaper than the 5000.  It also might get into places that don't want "good" cameras since it doesn't look the same :)

Comment: @jdlugosz - It is an awesome idea for a camera and I certainly see the applications that it would excel at - I was simply noting that having the fastest memory card on a camera that clearly isn't designed for speed seems kind of pointless. I'm going to delete my above comments because this comment section is getting to be a discussion. Good luck with the camera!

Answer (score -1):

@jdlugosz I once attended a SanDisk info session with the launch of a new product range and something I found valuable was that their Extreme range of memory cards have software embedded to clear the cameras buffer whilst capturing burst images. This will quite obviously not enhance the camera's frames per second rate, but will allow you to keep going at maximum fps for a little bit longer sometimes = getting the shot or not. With that said the desired classification for HD video is class 10 or above which as I understand deals more with the ability to handle bulk info rather than speed. http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/sd/extreme-uhs-1-45mbs/
This card will treat you well and more than likely outlive your camera, worth the investment.

Comment: How could it possibly do that, I wonder?

Comment: That would be a question the Sandisk tech's will be able to answer. I trust the cards and use them myself. I have 2x 8GB and 1x16GB Exteme Compact Flash cards and use them with my EOS40D @ 6.5fps. I found this comparison done on multiple cards, perhaps this helps to illustrate the superiority of the Extreme Pro series. http://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/nikon-d750/fastest-sd-card-speed-tests/

Comment: @jdlogosz However, the QX1 only has a 3.5fps (up to 15 images in the buffer) so I can't imagine that you would be too interested in high frame rate bursts all together. The ultra range would suit your needs just fine and they are tough little cards. When they said waterproof... I tested... 3x through the wash and works 100% These are also class 10 and thus suitable for HD video recording. http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/sd/ultra-uhs-1-class10-30mbs/ Very popular choice of card and bound to fit the budget.

Comment: @jdlugosz I suppose they could do that by having a buffer of their own, and then "lying" to the camera by indicating that the data had actually be written when it was still buffered. I suspect, though, that it's just sales/marketing people's fluffy interpretation of the card simply being fast enough that it can keep up with burst rates. Other than this, it's really not possible, because the SD card interface doesn't have anything to enable that kind of magical communication.

Comment: Also, were this true, I'd expect Sandisk to brag about it on their site or promotional materials [e.g. here](http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/sd/extreme-uhs-1-45mbs/?capacity=128GB), but they don't. In general, when sales or marketing people offer technical secrets as advantages of their products but it's not actually backed up in writing, _it is b.s._.